# Attach to linux process with microsoft visual studio?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio, attach-to-process

I'm developing python in Microsoft visual studio,

The python code is also executed in linux OS machine, which I have a connection to.

Is it possible for the visual studio to attach to the linux process,

for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a read through the [Cross-Platform Remote Debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Cross-Platform-Remote-Debugging) article supplied by Microsoft for PTVS.

You'll need to install the `ptvsd` package on your Linux machine, and with a simple import and set-up, you'll be able to connect to it remotely from Visual Studio.